# How do I simplify this code in Groovy that sets properties on an object if they are null?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using Grails to set properties on a domain class if the property is not null. Currently, the code looks something like this:

```
def product = Product.getById(5);

if (!product.Name) {
    product.Name = "Default Product"
}
if (!product.Price) {
    product.Price = 5;
}
if (!product.Type) {
    product.Type = "Shampoo"
}
```

What is a better way of implementing this code block in Groovy? I managed to simplify it to:

```
product.Name = product.Name ?: "Default Product"
product.Price = product.Price ?: 5
product.Type = product.Type = "Shampoo"
```

But I'd like to be able to do something like this (not valid code):

```
product {
    Name = product.Name ?: "Default Product",
    Price = product.Price ?: 5,
    Type = product.Type ?: "Shampoo"
}
```

What would you guys recommend I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `with` method call on your last example:

```
product.with {
    Name = Name ?: "Default Produce"
    Price = Price ?: 5
    Type = Type ?: "Shampoo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if simpler, but maybe more re-usable:

```
def setDefaults(obj, Map defaults) {
    defaults.each { k, v -> obj[k] = obj[k] ?: v }
}

setDefaults(product, [Name: 'Default Product', Price: 5, Type: 'Shampoo'])
```